# Need to reduce Query Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

My problem is below query takes 38 seconds to complete, 
I need to reduce this time as much as I can.
When I look at Execution plan : %54 cost spend on Dim_Customers Index Scanning.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

```
DECLARE @SalesPersonCode NVARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @StartDate       DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate         DATETIME

SET @SalesPersonCode = 'AC';
SET @StartDate       = '03/01/2012';
SET @endDate         = '03/31/2012';

SELECT AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Salesperson
             , Dim_SalesOrganisation.[Salesperson name]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Order Date]
             , Dim_Customers.[Customer number]
             , Dim_Customers.[Customer name]
             , Dim_Customers.[Area/state]
             , Dim_Customers.country
             , Dim_Customers.[Customer stop] AS [Customer Block]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Customer order stop] AS [Co Stop]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[First delivery date Header]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Last delivery date Header]
             , Dim_Customers.[User-defined field 6 - customer]
             , Dim_Customers.[Customer group name]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Contact Method]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Customer order number]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Price Level]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Item number]
             , Dim_Items.[Product group description]  AS [Item name]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Ordered quantity - basic U/M] AS [Quantity Ordered]
             , AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Ordered quantity - basic U/M] * AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Net price] AS [Order Line Total ]

FROM AA_FactSalesOrderDetails 
     LEFT JOIN
     Dim_SalesOrganisation
     ON
     AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Salesperson = Dim_SalesOrganisation.Salesperson
     LEFT JOIN
     Dim_Customers
     ON
     AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Dim_Customers_dKey = Dim_Customers.Dim_Customers_dKey
     LEFT JOIN
     Dim_Items
     ON
     AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Item number] = Dim_Items.[Item number]
     LEFT JOIN
     Dim_CustomerOrderTypes
     ON
     AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Customer order type] = Dim_CustomerOrderTypes.[Customer order type]



WHERE AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Order Date] 
      BETWEEN
      dbo.fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date(@StartDate)    /* !!!Procedural Approach!!! */
      AND
      dbo.fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date(@EndDate)      /* !!!Procedural Approach!!! */
      AND
      AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Salesperson = @SalesPersonCode
```

Comment: What does `dbo.fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date()` do? If the code is not obnoxiously long can you post it?

Comment: In addition to @Yuck's question, how many rows in the tables? How many rows get returned by this query? What is the data type of [Order Date] and the return data type of the function? Is there an index on [Order Date], Salesperson or any of the columns in the join criteria? Did you look at the execution plan to see where the time is being spent?

Comment: Is `Dim_Customers.Dim_Customers_dKey` have a clustered index covering it? Also, is `AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Dim_Customers_dKey` a foreign key to `Dim_Customers.Dim_Customers_dKey` with a covering index?

Comment: Thanks for your attention
Yuck : Code is obnoxiously long, around like 700 character
Aaron Bertrand : 3037 rows returned, around like 100 tables, I am not allowed to create a clustered index,  Time spent in Index Seek Dim Customers, others are below %20
Jesse C. Slicer : Unfortunately I am not allowed to cerate a clustered index, I must change the way of query if possible
                                    Thanks to all

Comment: If this is the query that returns the right logic, you can't magically "fix" the query or tell it to go faster, except perhaps removing those function calls (we can't tell you how to do that, because we have no idea what the function does or what data type it returns, but they can certainly be moved out of the query). Typically the way you "fix" slow queries is to improve your indexing strategy, ensure that the logic is correct, remove unnecessary joins or columns, update stats, validate the execution plan (and whether it is cached), etc.

Comment: I've found that having left joins makes things slower, the more left joins, the slower it gets. In one case what I did was create a separate "cached" table with the left joins, and then do a normal join between the two tables

Comment: Is there an index where Dim_Customers.Dim_Customers_dKey is the first column in the index? What exactly is the index that has the Scan that takes 54%?

Comment: Please add the code from the function, the data type of [Order Date], and confirm whether you are running SQL Server 2008 or an earlier version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date takes a value that is constant throughout the execution of the query, move those two calls (the one with startDate and the one with endDate to the top of your query and assign the returned values to declared variables. Then reference those declared variables below instead of calling the function within the where clause. That may help. Functions sometimes inhibit the formulation of a good query plan.

This talks a little about it
[Why do SQL Server Scalar-valued functions get slower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800017/why-do-sql-server-scalar-valued-functions-get-slower)
and this too
http://strictlysql.blogspot.com/2010/06/scalar-functions-on-where-clause.html

```
declare @m3StartDate Numeric(8,0)
Set @m3StartDate = fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date(@StartDate)
declare @m3EndDate Numeric(8,0)
Set @m3EndDate = fnc_M3_sql_datetime_to_M3_date(@EndDate)
...
WHERE AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Order Date] 
      BETWEEN @m3StartDate AND @m3EndDate
      AND
      AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.Salesperson = @SalesPersonCode
```

The type of the two @m3-- vars should be exactly the same as AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Order Date].

I would also examine the definition of the key on Dim_Customers that is getting the scan instead of a seek, and ensure Dim_Customers is indexed in a way that helps you if it isn't already.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/24/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-diffefence-and-usage-a-simple-note/

Comment: +1 but you'd have to validate using profiler whether the function calls are actually happening multiple times. In a lot of cases (and this gets better with each release) SQL Server is pretty good at optimizing these calls away - depends on the nature of the function and where they are used. Regardless I would still agree that they should be moved out of the main query.

Comment: I can't say definitively that it will improve the performance. Sometimes SQL Server works around the functions fine, and we can't see what's in the function. But given the restrictions the poster has mentioned, this is a simple thing to try, and his query is fairly simple so I didn't see a lot of other options.

Comment: I am sorry if I am talking irrelevant way, but is it possible to reduce time if I divide this query with UNION ALL keyword ?, by the way hatchet could you please show me how I can do your suggestion ?

Comment: How would you separate your query with UNION ALL? It seems like your WHERE clause is dictated only by criteria against one table in the join, and all of your joins are dictated by exactly one join criteria, so I'm not sure how you would break that up into separate queries.

Comment: Here goes the thing : 
When I remove the function ,  new time is 35 seconds

Comment: An error has occured : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: What type does the function return, and what type is AA_FactSalesOrderDetails.[Order Date]?

Comment: Then that is what you should use, and I've edited my answer to match. And that is the datatype of the [Order Date] column too, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet money that this version runs faster than 35 seconds.

Now, there still may be other optimizations possible (such as creating or improving indexes, which we can't know without seeing the plan), but I think I've cleaned up several issues in your query that should assist performance.

**EDIT** a few edits since apparently the user is running against 2000 even though the question is tagged 2008...

```
-- make sure you don't have an implicit conversion between varchar and nvarchar
DECLARE
  @SalesPersonCode NVARCHAR(4),
  @StartDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT
  @SalesPersonCode = N'AC', -- nvarchar needs N prefix!
-- get rid of the function call, I am guessing it just removes time
-- in which case, use the DATE data type instead.
  @StartDate       = '20120301',
  @EndDate         = '20120331';

-- since a salesperson can only have one code, and you are only pulling the name into the 
-- SELECT list (it will be the same for every row), use a constant and eliminate the join.

DECLARE @SalesPersonName NVARCHAR(255);

SELECT @SalesPersonName = SalesPerson_Name 
  FROM dbo.Dim_SalesOrganisation
  WHERE SalesPerson = @SalesPersonCode;

-- I've added table aliases which make the query MUCH, MUCH easier to read

SELECT f.Salesperson
     , Salesperson_name = @SalesPersonName
     , f.[Order Date]
     , c.[Customer number]
     , c.[Customer name]
     , c.[Area/state]
     , c.country
     , c.[Customer stop] AS [Customer Block]
     , f.[Customer order stop] AS [Co Stop]
     , f.[First delivery date Header]
     , f.[Last delivery date Header]
     , c.[User-defined field 6 - customer]
     , c.[Customer group name]
     , f.[Contact Method]
     , f.[Customer order number]
     , f.[Price Level]
     , f.[Item number]
     , i.[Product group description]  AS [Item name]
     , f.[Ordered quantity - basic U/M] AS [Quantity Ordered]
     , f.[Ordered quantity - basic U/M] * f.[Net price] AS [Order Line Total ]

    -- I've also added schema prefix. See below *
FROM 
     dbo.AA_FactSalesOrderDetails AS f
-- I've removed the join to Dim_SalesOrganisation as per above
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Customers AS c
       ON f.c_dKey = c.Dim_Customers_dKey
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Items AS i
       ON f.[Item number] = i.[Item number]
     -- I've removed the join to Dim_CustomerOrderTypes since it is never used
WHERE 
    -- in case [Order Date] is DATETIME and includes time information. See below **
    f.[Order Date] >= @StartDate 
    AND f.[Order Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)
    -- still need to restrict it to the stated salesperson
    AND f.SalesPerson = @SalesPersonCode;
```

`*` [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

`**` [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@SalesPersonCode".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 52
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".

Comment: SQL 2000?  Just change the variable declaration section at the top so you aren't immediately setting a default value, then SET those values right after they're declared.

Comment: You're using SQL Server 2000? Why is the question tagged SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it will work on SQL Server 2000. Please be accurate when you tag your question with a specific version - we don't much care what version of Management Studio you're running, we care what `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion');` says.

Comment: Nope I am running this code in MS SQL 2008 R2 Developer Edition 9.00.4035.00

Comment: That is not possible. 9.00.4035 is SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Although @hatchet is right in avoiding using functions on `WHERE` clause, I guess this is not the problem in this case, because it is used over scalar values (one could only be sure with the actual query plan).

Definitely, you can remove the reference to the table `Dim_CustomerOrderTypes`, that is not filtering nor returning any data. And I believe this query should improve performance using the following indexes:

```
-- to seek on [Salesperson] and scan on [Order Date]
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDXC ON AA_FactSalesOrderDetails([Salesperson], [Order Date]);

-- to seek on key
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDXC ON Dim_Customers([Dim_Customers_dKey]);

-- to seek only this index instead of reading from table
CREATE INDEX IDX0 ON Dim_SalesOrganisation([Salesperson], [Salesperson name]);

-- to seek only this index instead of reading from table
CREATE INDEX IDX0 ON Dim_Items ([Item number], [Product group description])
```

I hope these suggestions help you.