# Why execution time of a query and a function may be different

Tags: sql-server-2005

It's not clear for me why the execution time of scalar-function could be at least two times  longer than individual query, based on function's body.
Details:
I wrote sql-query (declaring variables as parameters) and covered it with "set statistics time on" and run it. After that I've covered the sql-query into scalar-function and executed it with statistics time on again. The result confused me: execution time in the second case was much longer than in the first case (at least two times longer).

Comment: can you give us the function?

Answer (score 0):

Scalar functions need to be ran once for every row, and cannot be optimized by the query plan engine. Read more in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/809789/2232256).